# Is there a way to create files in a VSCode-snippets-esque way?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode snippets I love and use a lot.

But what I find, is for React development for example, I'll have a file structure like:

```
/MyComponent
  MyComponent.tsx
  MyComponent.test.tsx
  MyComponent.style.tsx
  MyComponent.stories.tsx
```

Each of those files will require me using the mouse to create the file, and then call a snippet for.

Is there some VSCode native way (preferred) or well established plugin that will allow me to call a command palette tool to create all the files and their corresponding boilerplate?